# C++. reading shape name, length and width from file and using those to calculate area

Tags: c++

In this project I have a file named testShape.txt that contains a few shapes and information about those shapes, such as height, radius, length, and width. 
The first line of the .txt file is "Rectangle 2.44 3.6". The second line being "Sphere 1.82". (The 1.82 is the radius of the circle from which the sphere is created from.  Also, each shape has its own derived class, with shape being a pure virtual base class. I am able to read and print the text file, but I'm not sure how to use each element of the line from the .txt file. I have a pretty basic code set up to read the file.

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("testShapes.txt");

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
        if (line == "Rectangle")
        {
            Rectangle::Rectangle(line, line);
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

To sum up, my question is, how do i read each element from a line in a file and pass that to a class that does the calculations.

Comment: You don't want to read the entire line: you want to read a string (Rectangle or Sphere) and a double. You can do it like `myfile >> str >> d;`

Comment: The if (line = "Rectangle") snippet was me just seeing if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input file word by word while keeping track of what shape is being currently processed. Let's say your input file contains the following shapes with a different number of corresponding dimensions:

```
$cat testShapes.txt
Rectangle 2.44 3.6
Sphere 1.82
Square 1.11
Parallelepiped 3.33 4.44 5.55
```

Once you read the shape you know how many dimensions to read next.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    double d1, d2, d3;

    while (cin >> word)
    {
        cout << "shape: \""  << word << "\"" << endl;

        if (word == "Rectangle") {
           cin >> d1 >> d2;
           cout << "\tdimensions: "  << d1 << ", " << d2 << endl;
        }
        else if (word == "Sphere") {
           cin >> d1;
           cout << "\tdimension: "  << d1 << endl;
        }
        else if (word == "Square") {
           cin >> d1;
           cout << "\tdimension: "  << d1 << endl;
        }
        else if (word == "Parallelepiped") {
           cin >> d1 >> d2 >> d3;
           cout << "\tdimensions: "  << d1 << ", " << d2 << ", " << d3 << endl;
        }
        else {
           cout << "Unknow shape" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of reading from a file in this example the data is read from standard input `cin`. For example, on linux after compiling it you would run it as:

```
$a.out < testShapes.txt
```

It should be trivial to modify this example to calculate whatever you need from the values read for each shape.